# C++: How to template a collection?

Tags: c++, templates

Suppose I have a deque and a vector:

```
deque<someclass> d;
vector<similar_class> v;
```

Now, I have two different containers and two different--but similar--element classes.

I have one function that performs an operation that is useful for any of the following types:

```
deque<similar_class> a;
deque<someclass> b;
vector<similar_class> c;
vector<someclass> d;
```

How do I encode the 'collection_type' in a template?

---

For instance:

```
// starting with this function (which is fine)
template<class element>
element * my_func(deque<element> & collection)
{ ... }


// Now, how do I abstract this for a generic collection?
template<class collection, class element> 
element * my_func(collection<element> & c)
{ ... }
```

???

Comment: Have you considered `template <class Containter> element *my_func(Container &container)`?

Comment: What is the problem with the second `my_func`?

Comment: @UnholySheep `collection` would need to be a templated template argument.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
template<class collection, class element> 
element* my_func(collection<element> & c)
```

should be:

```
template <template <typename ...> class collection, class element> 
element* my_func(collection<element>& c)
```

You have other possible alternatives:

```
template <class C> 
typename C::pointer // or also auto or decltype(auto)
my_func(C& c)
```

Comment: Ha! knew there was a way built in :). Thank you!